# python command line syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried running a simple python file from the command line. I created a python file called script0.py with the following content

```
 print 2**2
```

I get a syntax error.

```
>>> python script0.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python script0.py
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

What is that? My first try with python has been really bad and the book of Mark Lutz is not helping. I use Python 2.7.

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to issue a shell command to Python. `python script0.py` doesn't go in an interactive Python session; it goes in the shell, a.k.a. command prompt.

Comment: I have no idea; that works just fine for me.  Do you have any leading spaces or other characters in the file?

Comment: @user2357112 is correct, you should post it as the answer

Comment: no, no leading spaces. How do I submit a simple python script that runs in the command prompt under windows?

Comment: I am using python 27 with Windows 10. When I simply type python I get errors too. Something is not right.

Comment: >>> python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined

Comment: @nia: You're still trying to issue shell commands to Python there.

Comment: what is the solution of the problem?

Comment: Stop trying to issue shell commands to Python. Use the command prompt - on Windows, the thing literally called "command prompt".

Comment: Thank you guys. It turns out that when I click the python icon it opens the interpreter, not just a command prompt. I didn't notice.

Answer (score 3):

You are running that code **from inside the python interpreter**. If your terminal is showing a leading `>>>` it means your inside python already, in there you can either type `print 2**2` directly, or exit and call `python script0.py`

My guess is that you inadvertently entered the python interpreter and thought you were still at the command prompt. Type `exit()` and try again.

[image: demo]

Comment: Nope it is Python 2.7.

Comment: Thanks. exit() exits the command prompt. I use Windows 10. Probably Python 2.7.12 doesn't work with windows 10.

Comment: @nia: Protip: don't blame your tools until you understand them. Python works fine on Windows 10. You're just doing it wrong.

Comment: You need to do something like this `C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Username\Desktop\my_python_script.py` changing the routes to those on your system

Comment: I was opening python interpreter in the command prompt. I just had to open a command prompt. Sorry for the stupid question and thanks a lot.